# Freeze svg animation by click

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have this svg code that produces 3 rectangles that change colors. I want to freeze them by clicking on any of these 3 rectangles, but I'm new to svg and I have no idea how to do it. I tried by using javascript, but it didn't work. Any ideas?

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" onclick="freezing()">
  <rect x="10" y="20" width="90" height="60">
    <animate id="a1" attributeName="fill" from="red" to="blue" dur="3s" fill="freeze"  />
  </rect>
  <rect x="10" y="120" width="90" height="60">
    <animate id="a2" attributeName="fill" from="blue" to="yellow" dur="3s" fill="freeze"  />
  </rect>
  <rect x="10" y="220" width="90" height="60">
    <animate id="a3" attributeName="fill" from="yellow" to="green" dur="3s" fill="freeze" />
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Comment: you want to freeze all of them or just the one you clicked on?

Comment: I want to freeze all of them independent with the rectangle I will click

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [SVGSVGElement#pauseAnimations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGSVGElement#methods) method to pause SMIL animations running inside this element.
To resume it you can call the `unpauseAnimations()` one.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
svg.onclick = (evt) => {
  if (svg.animationsPaused()) {
    svg.unpauseAnimations();
  }
  else {
    svg.pauseAnimations();
  }
};
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500" >
  <rect x="10" y="20" width="90" height="60">
    <animate id="a1" attributeName="fill" from="red" to="blue" dur="3s" fill="freeze"  />
  </rect>
  <rect x="10" y="120" width="90" height="60">
    <animate id="a2" attributeName="fill" from="blue" to="yellow" dur="3s" fill="freeze"  />
  </rect>
  <rect x="10" y="220" width="90" height="60">
    <animate id="a3" attributeName="fill" from="yellow" to="green" dur="3s" fill="freeze" />
  </rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is really difficult to combine SMIL animations in SVG with JavaScript. Here I replaced the animate elements with [Animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Animation) objects in JavaScript. An animation object have different methods like play(), pause() and cancel().

By calling [Element.getAnimations()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAnimations) you can get all the animations on an element. It is an array, so you need to iterate over it and pause all (in this case only one) the animations.

```js
let timingoptions = {
  duration: 3000,
  fill: 'forwards'
};

document.querySelector('rect:nth-child(1)').animate([
  {fill: 'red'},
  {fill: 'blue'}
], timingoptions);

document.querySelector('rect:nth-child(2)').animate([
  {fill: 'blue'},
  {fill: 'yellow'}
], timingoptions);

document.querySelector('rect:nth-child(3)').animate([
  {fill: 'yellow'},
  {fill: 'green'}
], timingoptions);

document.querySelector('svg').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.getAnimations().forEach(animation => animation.pause());
});
```

```html
<svg width="500" height="500">
  <rect x="10" y="20" width="90" height="60"/>
  <rect x="10" y="120" width="90" height="60"/>
  <rect x="10" y="220" width="90" height="60"/>
</svg>
```